# Share client data with Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Forms form that the user needs to fill and I have a script in Google Apps Script that processes the data. On the form submission event I want to pass a hidden string from the client to the form ("the client token [not Google account token]").

I tried those methods:

- Pass the data in the URL for example "myform.com/****?token=MY_TOKEN" and tried to retrieve it in the onFormSubmit(e) function (which is coupled with on form submit trigger), but the problem that the function does not access the client URL.
- Pass the data in the URL for example "myform.com/****?token=MY_TOKEN" and use it in the pre-filled forms but the problem is the user must see it and validate it to be considered as a response but I want it to be hidden.
- Use a web app and use JavaScript inside HTML to take the token and then pass it to the onFormSubmit(e) function, bit the problem that the function does not seem to recieve any information from any other function.
- Use localStorage between the web app and a frame cotaining the form but the same problem.

Is there any solution to pass a hidden data from the client to the onFormSubmit(e) function and use it later?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Why and why hide it? And why not a plain html form?

Comment: @TheMaster I want to use Google Forms because it is ready with a builder.
Hide it because it is a token for example.